# Can I get registries within different time periods with only one query?

Tags: sql, hsqldb

I have a TABLE within IBM ObjectServer that stores the alert status from network equipments.

In this table there are two fields that are relevant for this question: `LastOccurrence` and `Severity` (the names are self-explained).

`Severity` varies from 0 to 5, but I'm insterested in 4 values:

- 2: Info
- 3: Minor
- 4: Major
- 5: Critical

I have to count alerts within different timespans and show them in a table.

What I need can be better explained by the picture bellow:

[image: Summary table]

Currently I can achive this using the `UNION` operator.

But I was wondering if it is possible to do this with one single query.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways of doing this. One way is to GROUP BY the hour and then use a union to select sums of the grouping table.

First you need to convert the log into an SQL table. Suppose the table has two columns

```
CREATE TABLE LOG (TS TIMESTAMP, ET VARCHAR(10))

WITH EVENTS(HOURS, INFO, MINOR, MAJOR, CRITICAL) AS (
SELECT (LOCALTIMESTAMP - TS) INTERVAL HOUR, 
   COUNT(ET) FILTER (WHERE ET = 'Info'),
   COUNT(ET) FILTER (WHERE ET = 'Minor'),
   COUNT(ET) FILTER (WHERE ET = 'Major'),
   COUNT(ET) FILTER (WHERE ET = 'Critical')
   FROM LOG GROUP BY (LOCALTIMESTAMP - TS) INTERVAL HOUR
) 

SELECT 'Last 1 hour', SUM(INFO), SUM(MINOR), SUM(MAJOR), SUM(CRITICAL) FROM EVENTS WHERE HOURS < 1 UNION 
SELECT 'Last 6 hours', SUM(INFO), SUM(MINOR), SUM(MAJOR), SUM(CRITICAL) FROM EVENTS WHERE HOURS < 6 UNION
SELECT 'Last 12 hours', SUM(INFO), SUM(MINOR), SUM(MAJOR), SUM(CRITICAL) FROM EVENTS WHERE HOURS < 12
```

You can then select various periods counting by the hour and using SUM to calculate the totals.

Comment: In deed, the events don't come from a log, this is originally an IBM ObjectServer table. I'll edit the question for further details.